# Remove empty rows within a dataframe and check similarity

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text-mining

I am having some difficulties to select not empty fields using regex (findall) within my dataframe, looking for words contained into a text source:

```
text = "Be careful otherwise police will capture you quickly."
```

I will need to look for words that ends with `ful` in my text string, then looking for words that ends with full in my dataset.

```
Author      DF_Text

31       Better the devil you know than the one you don't      
53       Beware the door with too many keys.      
563      Be careful what you tolerate. You are teaching people how to treat you. 
41       Fear the Greeks bearing gifts.      
539      NaN
51       The honey is sweet but the bee has a sting.      
21       Be careful what you ask for; you may get it.
```

(from csv/txt file).
I need to extract words ending with `ful` in `text`, then look at both DF_Text (thus Author) which contains words ending with `ful` and appending results in a list.

```
n=0
for i in df['DF_Text']:
        print(re.findall(r"\w+ful", i))
        n=n+1
        print(n)
```

My question is: how can I remove empty rows(`[]`) from the analysis (`NaN`) and report the author names (e.g. `563`, `21`) related to?
I will be happy to provide further information, in case it would be not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.findall` instead of looping with `re.findall`:

```
df["found"] = df["DF_Text"].str.findall(r"(\w+ful)")

df.loc[df["found"].str.len().eq(0),"found"] = df["Author"]

print (df)

   Author                                            DF_Text      found
0      31   Better the devil you know than the one you don't         31
1      53                Beware the door with too many keys.         53
2     563  Be careful what you tolerate. You are teaching...  [careful]
3      41                     Fear the Greeks bearing gifts.         41
4     539                                                NaN        NaN
5      51        The honey is sweet but the bee has a sting.         51
6      21       Be careful what you ask for; you may get it.  [careful]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the .notna() function of Pandas to get rid of that row in your datafrae. l.
Something like this

```
df = df[df['DF_Text'].notna()]
```

And please note that Python calls the dataframe twice before overwriting it, this is correct.

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.htm